# Undefined Method 'path' For StringIO in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I'm using the following snippet in a Rails app:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://..."
uri = URI.parse(self.url)
file = open(uri)
puts "path: #{file.path}"
```

Which works on some files from the web, then crashes on others with:

> undefined method `path' for #< StringIO:0x00000102a47240 >

Any way to fix this strange, intermittent problem?

Comment: Could you provide example URLs with and without this error?

Comment: @floatless Thanks, it seemed to be issues with extremely small files not creating a backed file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use Open::URI like that.

Simply do:

```
file = open(url)
```

Then you can `read` the file because you have an IO-type object:

```
body = file.read
```

or

```
body = open(url).read
```

If you need the path, parse the URL with URI and get the path that way.

Answer (score 14):

I'm definitely late to the party but...

The root of this problem is that if you use `open(url)` on a file smaller than 10kb it will convert it into a string IO object auto-magically instead of using a Tempfile. The StringIO object as everyone has pointed out does not have the `path` method defined on it.

The default (10kb) is set by the `StringMax` constant...

http://yard.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/OpenURI/Buffer.html

```
if defined?(OpenURI) && OpenURI::Buffer.const_defined?(StringMax)
  OpenURI::Buffer.send('remove_const', StringMax)
  OpenURI::Buffer.send('const_set', StringMax, 0)
end
```

Boom problem, solved!

p.s. make sure to use #send otherwise you can't access the #remove_const and #cont_set methods.
p.p.s. I wouldn't advise setting it to zero if you do a lot of small IO as the tempfiles created will probably be worse than just changing your code to properly use StringIO. It all depends on yer use case.

Comment: You just saved my bacon!

Comment: This did not work for me unless I changed all the `StringMax` constants in the snippet to strings.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html) SrtingIO dosnt have a function name path.

Comment: It actually had it: https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/StringIO/path

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not acceptable the solution to call #read method after open().

So I have added this piece of code in config/initializers

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  if defined?(OpenURI) && OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax
    OpenURI::Buffer.send(:remove_const, 'StringMax')
    # default value is 10240 (nearly 10Kb)
    OpenURI::Buffer.const_set('StringMax', 1000)
  end
end
```